# How to not return an specific column using PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: java, spring, repository

I know the title may sound a bit confusing, but I did not know how to summarize my problem on the title.

My main problem is that I do not want to return an specific column using PagingAndSortingRepository. Imagine the following scenario:

I have two entitys, one called Users:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotBlank()
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "password")
  private String password;

}
```

And one called Cars:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotBlank()
  @Column
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
  @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private User owner;

}
```

I want to return a list of car by user's name using PagingAndSortingRepository. Using the following interface I can achieve that:

```
public interface CarRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Car, Long> {

  List<Car> findByOwner_name(String name);

}
```

However, with said interface the result will also return the user's password on it. I could use a for on each element of the list and set the password as null, but it would be troublesome in a scenario where there is a user with lots of cars. How could I make it so that the result of the list come with the specific column, password, without any value to the user?

Thanks in advance =).

ps: I thought about returning a list of projection instead of a list of Car, but I do not know how to say it to the projection that just one attribute from the class should be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Projections` for this purpose.  It is documented in detail [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

Create an interface with fields you want to include in the entity to be returned.
For example, in your case it would be like this

```
interface CarSummary {

  String getName();
  Long getId();
  UserSummary getUser();

  interface UserSummary {
    String getName();
    Long getId();
  }
}
```

and modify your repository like this

```
public interface CarRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Car, Long> {
    Collection<CarSummary> findByOwner_name(String name);  
}
```

Comment: That's exactly it that I was looking for. How to call another interface projection on a projection =), thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Projections can be used recursively. Something like this should work:

```
interface CarPojection{

      Long getId();
      String getName();
      UserSummary getUser();

      interface UserSummary {
        Long getId();
        String getName();
      }
    }
```

And your repository should return `CarPojection`
Find more information in Spring docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 1):

You can return a subset of data by providing a matching constructor in your entity class.

```
@Query("select new com.foo.bar.entity.User(u.id, u.name) from User u where u.name = ?1")
List<User> findByOwner_name(String name);
```

In you class `User` just provide the constructor and other properties will be left `null`:

```
public User(Long id, String name) {
    // ...       
}
```