# Spring data JPA get child collection attributes using projections

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I would like to fetch only few attributes from child collection entitites. So, is it possible using Spring JPA projections and Spring JPA repository?

Also, it should not execute multiple queries. Just one query to fetch the selected attributes form child collection.

I want to evaluate options first if it is available in Spring JPA before considering any other alternative.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666651/how-to-not-return-an-specific-column-using-pagingandsortingrepository/48666860#48666860

Comment: This works fine if it is a just single child entity. What if, it is a child collection or list of child entities?

Comment: Have you solved it? @MaheshSrinivas